# How to dynamically render a nested component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a child element based on the state in its parent. I tried to do the following (simplified version of the code):

```
class DeviceInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentTab: "General",
    };
    this.tabsMap = {
      General: 
        <React.Fragment>
          <GeneralCard
            id={this.props.id}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
  }

  navToggle(tab) {
    this.setState({ currentTab: tab });
  }
  this.tabsMap = {
      General: 
        <React.Fragment>
          <GeneralCard
            id={this.props.id}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <Nav className="nav-tabs ">
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink
                className={this.state.currentTab === "General" ? "active" : ""}
                onClick={() => {
                  this.navToggle("General");
                }}
              >
                General
              </NavLink>
        </div>
        { this.tabsMap[this.state.currentTab] }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

But it did not work properly. Only when I put the contents of the tabsMap straight in the render function body it works (i.e. as a react element rather then accessing it through the object). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making `tabsMap` an attribute which is only set when the component is constructed, make a method that returns the object, and call it from `render`:

```
getTabsMap() {
  return {
    General: 
      <React.Fragment>
        <GeneralCard
          id={this.props.id}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
   }
};

render() {
  ...
  { this.getTabsMap()[this.state.currentTab] }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defining instance property with `this.tabsMap` (should be syntax error):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  tabsMap = { General: <div>Hello</div> };

  // Syntax error
  // this.tabsMap = { General: <div>World</div> };

  render() {
    // depends on props
    const tabsMapObj = {
      General: <div>Hello with some props {this.props.someProp}</div>
    };
    return (
      <FlexBox>
        {this.tabsMap['General']}
        {tabsMapObj['General']}
      </FlexBox>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57543567]

### Edit after providing code:

Fix the bug in the constructor (Note, don't use constructor, it's error-prone, use class variables).

Moreover, remember that constructor runs once before the component mount if you want your component to be synchronized when properties are changed, move it to render function (or make a function like proposed).

```
class DeviceInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    // this.props.id not defined in this point
    this.tabsMap = {
      General: 
        <React.Fragment>
          <GeneralCard
            id={props.id}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
  }

  render() {
    // make a function to change the id
    this.tabsMap = {
      General: 
        <React.Fragment>
          <GeneralCard
            id={this.props.id}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
    };
    return (
      <>
        { this.tabsMap[this.state.currentTab] }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The code crashes with the following error: Failed to compile
./src/components/DeviceInfo.js
  Line 14:  'tabsMap' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: You not showing complete code, this.tabsMap should have been syntax error in class context, see sandbox I provided

Comment: Added some missing parts in the code. Still not the full code, for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a this binding issue. Not sure if your tabsMap constant should have `this` in front of it.

Alternative answer... you can inline the expression directly in the render as

```
{ this.state.currentTab === 'General' && <GeneralCard id={this.props.id} /> }
```